# CodeIgniter Undefined Variable while trying to create subview

Tags: codeigniter, variables, undefined, subview

Hi I am new to CodeIgniter and am taking a tutorial. I ran into an error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: subview
Filename: admin/_layout_modal.php
Line Number: 7
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: .php
```

I followed the tutorial to the tee and I cant seem to find out where I am going wrong.

here is the controller

```
    <?php
class User extends Admin_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function login() {
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/login';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $this->data);
    }
}
```

and the view

```
<?php $this->load->view($subview); ?>
```

Please help...

Comment: Could you show us that tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

If you gave script from your .php file not tutorial then everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably typing the wrong url in when you try to access the page.  Make sure you are loading "admin/user/login" instead of "admin/dashboard/modal".

Answer (score 0):

If you are following tutplus tutorial- building cms with codeigniter, First watch two episodes, Managing User Part 1 and Managing User Part 2 and then Start building, Your question will be answered on Part 2.... the dashboard has to declare the subview variable **and** 
**CREATE THAT admin/dashboard/index.php file in views**

```
class Dashboard extends Admin_Controller{


public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index(){

    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/dashboard/index';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main',$this->data);
}
public function Modal(){
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal',$this->data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't need to pass data to $this. Just pass the data to

```
$data['variable_name']=data;
```

pass this $data variable to view through load class.